# How can I get my Google Groups via API? I am NOT admin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-groups

I want to get all my groups but I am not an admin

I know how to fetch groups if I am admin. But if not - I don't understand. Also I can see its via website

**My steps:**

1. I do auth with Google and with scope

```
[
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/groups",
]
```

2. I fetch groups by GET. Url: `"https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?domain=konstructly.com"`
3. I get the next problem:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### My question

How can I get my Google Groups via Google API?

I tried:

1. Auth with scope

```
[
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/groups",
]
```

2. GET `"https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?domain=konstructly.com"`

Expectation:
List of my groups

Actual result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The google groups api doesnt work that way.  Its used for managing a google workspace domains google groups.  Not the google groups a user has access to.

Comment: Retrieving information from the AdminSDK Directory APIs can only be done from an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Google Workspace Admin SDK, use the Groups Service from Google Apps Script, more specifically [GroupsApp.getGroups()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app#getGroups())